# Question about closing

Tags: discussion

The following question has 5 votes to close, but it is not closed :  [Preparing for Set Theory Research](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134725/preparing-for-set-theory-research#comment347177_134725)

What is going on here?  I'm not trying to start a discussion of the merits of this question (though obviously one can discuss this if needed -- I think that everyone made their opinion known on the comments thread, and I am not going to argue if people decide it should stay open).  I'm just trying to understand the 2.0 closing mechanism.

Comment: Does this help - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/?cb=1

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais : Not sure how this answers the question.  It's not marked "on hold" either.

Comment: Might be a glitch but I didn't see it on MSO - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Closed now, probably was a glitch...

Comment: Ah, ok.  Probably just something acting weird since they are changing the close mechanism.

Comment: @Francois, Andy: I don't think it's a glitch. There are **six** closing votes on that question. But note that the new closing system has been deployed at this time, so it might be that.

Comment: Might also be that Harry's vote didn't count somehow...

Comment: @AsafKaragila : So we need *six* votes to close now instead of five?

Comment: I have no idea. It might be some mixture on the close votes too.

Comment: I didn't see that announced anywhere.

Comment: The post http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134737/computing-simplicial-groups-of-kan-sets was closed with 5 votes.

Comment: I have a feeling close votes don't count while users are suspended. Anybody want to get suspended?

Comment: I seem to recall it showing four votes to close at one point, and then a bit later it showed only one vote to close. So something was peculiar with that.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais : Sounds like a fun experiment.  I'd be game for it -- maybe a suspension would give me a chance to get some real work done :).  I guess the order of events has to be as follows : 1. Someone posts a fake question, 2. I vote to close it, 3. I'm suspended, and 4. Other people vote to close it.

Comment: @AndyPutman, OK I can unsuspend you right after to make sure you don't get work done :)

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais : OK, I'll log off and post a question under a fake account.  I'll then vote to close and flag the post for you to suspend me.  You then edit the question to let people know that they should then vote to close.  Sound good to you?

Comment: @AndyPutman, OK. Go ahead!

Comment: You guys... don't you think it's better to test this on the Dev version of MO? (It also has the new closure system)

Comment: It's OK... it's for *science*, Asaf!

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais : Here's the fake question : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134759/question-to-test-whether-suspended-users-votes-to-close-count

Comment: Experimental failure... I did observe a very brief delay with five votes before actual closure. This confirms the glitch hypothesis where the delay was, for some reason, much longer and a sixth vote got in in the mean time.

Comment: (Fake question deleted.)

Comment: Hahaha! Fun times on meta!

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais A note: In general, don't try to test suspensions that way. A few mods were (lightly -- nothing serious) admonished a yearish ago for doing a similar experiment. Try to avoid experimenting with any action that sends an email out. :)

Comment: Also, yes, there was a similar situation when posts on which newly elected mods had voted to close/delete in the past would get closed/deleted with _less_ votes (because moderator votes are binding). I guess the system checks if the post has reached the threshold every time someone close/delete votes.

Comment: Agreed, @Manishearth.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Anyway, once the chat accounts bug is fixed you shall have access to the secret moderator chatroom (I could manually grant it, but I'm too sleepy right now :P), where you can ask for advice on moderating the site and help using the tools (I'm pretty sure most of the current mod tools weren't there in the past). Hope to see you there!

Comment: @Manishearth, I tried it a couple of times before I realized there was a bug. It would have been handy a few times but we figured most of the new features by now.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais huh, looks like you already requested access. Granted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that this was a glitch in the closing system. There was an unusual delay between the fifth vote and actual closure during which a sixth vote was cast.

Answer (score 2):

Just to let Francois Dorais know -- I'm still suspended on meta, but I'll accept and vote up your answer once my suspension period is over.  My suspension on the main site has been lifted.

Comment: It can take an hour or so before suspension is lifted from meta. (It's useful for keen eyed observers, so they know there's a problem with moderators fighting over some suspension...)

Comment: This has been a very educational evening.

Comment: Wow, the fun just doesn't stop!

Comment: Well, with all the experience I have from testing the quirks and features of the SE system... I'm just glad there's something to do with this knowledge. :-)